# Regarding Filter on a List

Tags: filter

on a list on Filter section i.e. 'show items only when following is true' is limited to only 10 conditions only and I have 25 conditions/rules   to apply (due to lot of users) so that I can create a new view and I am not sure how to apply those ? Any idea's.

Answer (score 0):

Go to SharePoint Designer and convert your list view web part to a data view web part. Once this is done, you will see options for the data view web part allowing you to add filters. A new window opens allowing you to enter more than 10 filter criteria.

Comment: Hi lem,Thanks for your response. Even It allows only 10 filter conditions. So I am Trying to use xslt filter but still facing issues. Any Alternatives

Comment: hi can you tell me what you have done using the data view web part already and what you have done using xslt filters also so I can update my answer to your question. thanks! :)

Comment: on a Data view webpart on a filter section I tried to add more than 10 conditions/rules it never allows me (like if person equals to 'shreyas' or if person equal to 'Bill'...) ? As an alternative I used xslt view filter but it never shows some Items like if assigned.id = 100 it should show some user but never shows some of users with above Id. Any alternatives please